# mysql_fetch_array add all rows?

Tags: php, mysql

How can you add all the rows from a mysql_query to a mysql_fetch_array()? I want to be able to do it as efficiently as possible as it could be working with quite a few rows.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Please clarify your question. Do you want to sum certain row values?

Comment: What's wrong with the standard `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { echo $row['id']; }`?

Comment: Nope, just create a nested array with a mysql_query(). I guess mysql_fetch_array() only gets one row, and I need to get all of them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The most common way:

```
$rows = array();

while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

[as shown in the examples in the documentation.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Comment: I couldn't bring myself to write this answer.

Answer (score 11):

```
<?php

$db = new mysqli("localhost", "foo_dbo", "pass", "foo_db", 3306);

$startTime = microtime(true);

$result = $db->query("select * from users");

$users = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC); // faster

// while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) $users[] = $row; //slower

echo sprintf("%d users fetched in %s secs", 
    count($users), number_format(microtime(true) - $startTime, 6, ".", ""));

$db->close();

?>
```

**EDIT** some runtime stats

```
$users = $result->fetch_all()

  1000 users fetched in 0.001462 secs
  5000 users fetched in 0.005493 secs
 15000 users fetched in 0.015517 secs
 50000 users fetched in 0.051950 secs
100000 users fetched in 0.103647 secs
```

vs.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) $users[] = $row; 

  1000 users fetched in 0.001945 secs
  5000 users fetched in 0.008101 secs
 15000 users fetched in 0.023481 secs
 50000 users fetched in 0.081441 secs
100000 users fetched in 0.163282 secs
```

interesting :)

Comment: A better answer, if only because it avoids a "relatively slow" PHP `while` loop, which could matter slightly if there are 5 zillion rows.

Comment: Your +1 is from me, ..interesting.

Comment: lol - just a shame you're not the questioner asking about efficiency :P