# php_mysql_assoc ignores first record

Tags: php, mysql

Hi there I'm trying to query my database to get all the records that share the same "ITEMID" the table is a transaction list of operations done on items in the database.

I've checked the SQL query in phpmyadmin and it works correctly but when I run the php code it ignores the first record every time. Here's my code

```
<?php 
 // Get the quantity of each item 
 $sql1 = 'SELECT  `IDPENTERED` ,  `ITEMID` ,  `QTY` ,  `VALUE` FROM  `tblpieceentered` 
  WHERE  `ITEMID` =307 ' ;

 echo $sql1."<br>";

 // Retrieve all the data from the table
 $result1 = mysql_query($sql1)
 or die(mysql_error()); 

 // store the record of the table into $row1
 $row1 = mysql_fetch_array( $result1 ); 

 $i = 1; 
 $num = mysql_num_rows ($result1);

 echo "Num rows: $num <br>"; 

 while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc ( $result1)) {
    $data_array[$i] = $row1;
$i++;
 }

echo "<pre>";
print_r ($data_array);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

The Result is:

```
SELECT `IDPENTERED` , `ITEMID` , `QTY` , `VALUE` FROM `tblpieceentered` WHERE `ITEMID`     =307 
Num rows: 5 

Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [IDPENTERED] => 1999
            [ITEMID] => 307
            [QTY] => -1
            [VALUE] => -0.21
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [IDPENTERED] => 2507
            [ITEMID] => 307
            [QTY] => -10
            [VALUE] => -2.1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [IDPENTERED] => 3039
            [ITEMID] => 307
            [QTY] => 1
            [VALUE] => 0.21
        )

[4] => Array
        (
            [IDPENTERED] => 3040
            [ITEMID] => 307
            [QTY] => -1
            [VALUE] => -0.21
        )

)
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks
Sean

Comment: Off topic addition to my answer: unless you want your array to start at '1', you can just use `$data_array[] = $row` and skip the $i counter. It will append every row to the end of the array.

Answer (score 1):

mysql_fetch_array fetches the first row already. You don't add this row in your array. The while loop continues with the second row.

Answer (score 1):

There goes your first record:

```
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array( $result1 );
```

The loop starts on the next (second) record:

```
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc ( $result1))
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are fetching the first item **before** the while loop.

Remove the `$row1 = mysql_fetch_array( $result1 );` line, and you should be good.

Alternatively, if you wish to access the first row before the loop, you can use a [`do-while`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php) loop instead:

```
// store the record of the table into $row1
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array( $result1 ); 
$i = 1; 
$num = mysql_num_rows ($result1);
echo "Num rows: $num <br>";
do {
   $data_array[$i] = $row1;
   $i++;
} while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc ( $result1));
```

Answer (score 1):

use mysqli and fetch_all will be much more efficient:

[mysql_fetch_array add all rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643340/mysql-fetch-array-add-all-rows/4643388#4643388)

Comment: Thanks @f00 I'll give it a try later today as the query returns over 1500 records and the database is growing all the time.