# retrieving many rows php-mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table for example

```
+------+---------+------+
| id   | item_id | type |
+------+---------+------+
|    1 |       2 | book |
|    1 |       1 | pen  |
+------+---------+------+
```

I want retrieve all the data where id=1 in a php script, here is the code i used

```
 <?php 
    $stat="select item_id, type from tb where id=1"; 
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $stat); 
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    print_r($result); 
  ?>
```

the result is: `Array ( [item_id] => 2 [type] => book )` 
and that is only the first row, how to retrieve all the rows in the php code?

Comment: See the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643340/mysql-fetch-array-add-all-rows)

Answer (score 5):

Use this

```
 <?php 
    $stat="select item_id, type from tb where id=1"; 
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $stat); 
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        print_r($result); 
    }
  ?>
```

*by the way: i would call the `$stat` variable `$query` (as it is your query). The `$query` variable actually contains a result, so I would call that `$result` and your fetch array might be called something else too..*

Answer (score 1):

You have a function called mysql_fetch_array to read about at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Try this example:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Persons");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'];
  echo "<br />";
  }

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

For more http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Answer (score 1):

Well. For oneyou can do that:

```
<?php
    $stat = "SELECT `item_id`, `type` FROM `tb` WHERE `id` = 1"; 
    $query = mysqli_query( $con, $stat );

    while ( null !== ( $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $query ) ) )
    {
        print_r( $result );
    } 
?>
```