# MySQL equivalent for pg_fetch_all()

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, postgresql

i created the following PHP file:

```
if (isset($_GET['review']))
    $query = "SELECT text, rating, date, member FROM reviews WHERE users = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['review']) . "'";
else if (isset($_GET['rating']))
    $query = "SELECT ROUND(avg_rating, 2) as avg, num_recensioni FROM avg_voti WHERE users = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['rating']) . "'";
else if (isset($_POST['usersId']))
    $query = "SELECT id, name, desc, addr FROM users WHERE id = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['usersId']) . "' ORDER BY name ASC";

$result = pg_query($link, $query);
$arr = pg_fetch_all($result);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Now, since i changed the database from Postegres to MySQL i need to "convert" that code. So i changed the last three lines in this way:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$arr = mysqli_fetch_all($result);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

But `mysqli_fetch_all()` seems to be undefined. What can i use the get the same of `pg_fetch_all()` ? Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** My PHP version is 5.4.39

Answer (score 1):

As the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) said for the function `mysqli_fetch_all()` it requires a PHP version >= 5.3.0. Check yours

> HOW TO check PHP version:
>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php

**UPDATE:**

- Check if in your server is installed the `mysqlnd` driver (See same DOCs page)
- Try with mysqli_fetch_array()

**UPDATE 2:**

*METHOD 1:*

> HOW TO use `mysqli_fetch_array()` to fetch all rows:
>   [mysql_fetch_array add all rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643340/mysql-fetch-array-add-all-rows)

Next code is `mysql` function instead of `mysqli` but it will work if you change the function name

```
$rows = array();

while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

---

*METHOD 2:*

> HOW TO use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` to fetch all rows:
>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php#87201

```
// Read records
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table;") or die(mysql_error());
// Put them in array
for($i = 0; $array[$i] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); $i++) ;
// Delete last empty one
array_pop($array);
```

*"You need to delete the last one because this will always be empty.
By this you can easily read the entire table to an array and preserve the keys of the table columns. Very handy."*

Comment: My PHP version is 5.4.39

Comment: Regarding `mysqlnd` i'm on a shared hosting, so i can't install it.
`mysqli_fetch_array()` works with single rows, how to use it in my case to replace `mysqli_fetch_all()`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final solution:

pg_fetch_all() use (for Postegres):

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$arr = mysqli_fetch_all($result);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Equivalent for MySQL:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```